# Как конвертировать SCSS файлы в SASS

Tags: node.js, gulp, sass, scss

Желательно средствами gulp-sass или другим плагином для gulp

Comment: а можно узнать для чего? Просто если Вы хотите работать с `.scss` в `.sass`, то конвертации для этого не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Для конвертации можно [использовать](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-convert) плагин `sass-convert`.

Пример [использования](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-convert#usage):

```
var vfs = require('vinyl-fs');
var converter = require('sass-convert');

vfs.src('./input/**/*.+(sass|scss|css)')
  .pipe(converter({
    from: 'sass',
    to: 'scss',
  }))
  .pipe(vfs.dest('./output'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Я добавляю в скрипты (package.json) и запускаю в терминале npm run watch-css

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass src/scss/App.scss -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass src/scss/App.scss -o src/ --watch --recursive"
```